# Run code in background

Tags: ios, core-location

I'm currently getting the user's location via :

```
CLLocationManager *locationManager;

locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone; 

locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters;

[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

I need to run this task in the background each 30 min to check my user's location, even if he's not running the app.

Is this feasible ?

Comment: You can not just check the location every 30 min. You can either get the location bij major location change or every location update. You can of course als check whether the last location change was 30 min. ago.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/voyage11/Location?

Use this code.you can set time after how much time you want to call it. I have tried many codes, but i found this as most accurate and list battery issue.This is also awesome for background location service.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but unfortunately, this is for "refresh the app when it is in background mode" while i need to refresh the app when it's not even in background mode, not even launched on the device, i need to call a method even if the app is not running nor opened after a device reboot...

Comment: I guess then it is not possible to run the location service.